# Data gets unassigned when calling from another function

Tags: typescript, class, abstract-class

Okay to be honest this is the first time I worked with classes in typescript, but something like this is supposed to work in other languages if I'm not mistaken?
So I read I could use abstract class for this:

```js
type Cfg = {
    config:
        | Options<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>
        | Configuration<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>
        | undefined;
};

abstract class DB {
    public static orm: any;
    public static em: EntityManager<any> &
        EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>;

    public static async Initialize(configs: Cfg) {
        DB.orm = await MikroORM.init(configs.config);
        DB.em = DB.orm.em;
        console.log(typeof DB.em); // <= This will display DB.em correct type 
    }
}
```

Then I'd initialize it in my main function, that is run the function, since construction of abstract classes is forbidden.

```js
const main = async () => {
    await DB.Initialize({ config: mikroConfig! });
};
```

```js
export async function LogUserIn(
    code: string,
    username: string,
    password: string
): Promise<ServerResponse> {
    console.log(typeof DB.em); // Here it says undefined.
    return {
        response: "200",
    };
```

The function above is executed  before the LogUserIn. Since static classes are not added into typescript I read it wasn't a bad option to use abstract classes instead, I know this isn't a practice in other languages but since I'm new to typescript I took this advice. DB doesn't get initialized across all files in which it gets included. All three of this sections are in separate files. When I call DB.Initialize in the file with LogUserIn function everything seems to work, but I need to be able to use it's properties across all other files, and initializing the class in every time wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: Why do you want to use `abstract` when there is no inheritance in your example? Also, it would be helpful to clearly explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I hope I explained it a bit better, already talked with two others we couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Sorry, stupid question but I have to ask it -- you declared a function `main` in your code but you haven't shown where it is called. Are you calling it? Before `LogUserIn`?

Comment: Yes, since codebase got somewhat large, I provided only the necessary code.